# Trying to stream text over RTSP using Gstreamer

Tags: rtsp, gstreamer

I'm trying to develop an application which transmits processed data over RTSP so that another application can receive the data and do other stuff with it. The trouble is, it seems that not many people seems to use RTSP or/and Gstreamer to stream text(XML) data so I'm having difficulties looking for the right resources.

So at the server side (my application), I have this:

```
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(m_Factory, "( appsrc name=mysrc ! application/x-rtp,pt=98 ! rtpgstpay name=pay0 pt=98 )");
```

And I'm testing the connection by running the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test use-pipeline-clock=true debug=true ! application/x-rtp,payload=98 ! fakesink dump=true
```

When I run both of them, I confirmed that the callback function on the server side for "need-data" signal was being called continuously and the debug output from rtspsrc gave me 200 OK response all the way from OPTIONS request to PLAY request, except that the fakesink didn't dump anything and I don't see any data packet on Wireshark except for the requests and ACK's. So it seems that the connection can be made between the two, except that no actual data is being transferred between them.

And after a few seconds from the connection, I get this debug output from gstreamer on server side (GST_DEBUG=3)

```
0:00:13.646758533  4844 0x7f3508003940 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:3068:gst_rtsp_media_set_state: media 0x1f4ada0 was not prepared
0:00:13.676328927  4844 0x7f34d8004590 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3643:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<mysrc:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:13.676967874  4844 0x7f34b8001540 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3643:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<appsrc3:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:13.677498868  4844 0x7f34b8001680 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3643:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<appsrc4:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
```

and after exactly 20 seconds, I get this:

```
0:00:33.676438806  4844 0x7f34c0001f70 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:2127:wait_preroll: failed to preroll pipeline
0:00:33.676619321  4844 0x7f34c0001f70 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:2384:gst_rtsp_media_prepare: failed to preroll pipeline
0:00:33.681136801  4844 0x7f34c0001f70 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:678:find_media: client 0x1ec83b0: can't prepare media
0:00:33.684604205  4844 0x7f34c0001f70 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:2210:handle_describe_request: client 0x1ec83b0: no media
```

It seems that only one tiny step is missing to get the data packets actually transmitted from my application, but so far I haven't had any luck identifying it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello hope you found a way of doing this. Any suggestions on how to achieve this would really help, i am looking the same to stream text via RTP/rtsp along with parallel video stream as another RTP session. Any pointers would really help....